# Deleting specific lines and duplicates from a 11GB wordlist text file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, sort

I have an `11GB` word-list file which is already sorted as each word is on its own line.

I need to remove duplicates and lines starting from `077`.

I guess I need to run `sed` and `sort -u` together but I also want a live output `display what's happening in terminal` and if possible display the `time left`.

All of this in one command and it must be able to run optimally at full performance under a `Live CD` or possibly installed `Backtrack 5 rc3`.

Time is not very important but if there is a way for me to calculate the ETA, I might be able to borrow my dad's i7 based CPU which should process it faster obviously otherwise I'll have to use an older core 2 CPU.

The problem I'm facing with `sort` command is that under a `VMware` player running it live, it doesn't have enough space so I have to specify temp files on my `32GB` USB by using the `-T` command. I guess this won't be a problem had I installed Linux.

So please give me the complete command, be it `sed`,`sort`,`awk` to do this `(whichever is most optimal)`.

Comment: You might want to include a sample of the file, so people can see what you are dealing with. And any approaches you have tried yourself.

Comment: @jasonwryan umm how do i give a sample of 11gb file lol. Anyways just imagine the file contains 1 password on each line like a list. You would be familiar if you ever used a password dictionary file. Also i know how to run those command individually but they take a lot of time since its a huge file, i just want simply it and get the additional options listed in one command.

Answer (score 7):

Use `pv` for progress. You don't need a tempfile since you're only removing text. Just overwrite the file in place. If the file is already sorted, you don't need `sort -u`, just `uniq`.

```
pv file | {
  uniq | grep -v '^077'
  perl -e 'truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT'
} 1<> file
```

The perl line is to truncate the file at the point were `grep` finished to write.

Note that since you're writing the file in-place, if you make a mistake, you won't be able to go back.

Comment: do i copy this whole script and paste into terminal after changing the input/output file ? I also need to install pv for this to work. Is this script any better then what Leonid has suggested below ? Because i rather not sacrifice performance.

Comment: Yes. Mine is a simplified version of Leonid's (`uniq < infile | greo -v '^077' > outfile`) with the addition of the progress bar (pv), and inplace editing (so you don't need extra free space).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can have ETA or any progress display without significantly increasing the complexity of the sed/awk/shell script (and slowing the whole thing as a result). If you just want it to be as fast as possible, just try `cat source_file | uniq | sed -n -e '/^077/!p' > dest_file`. For an approximation of the progress display, you might want to watch the growing size of the `dest_file` with that command running in background or in another terminal.

Comment: Thanks, this one looks pretty straight forward, its running uniq and then piping into sed to remove numbers starting from 077 and saving the output in the destination file. I have also heard of awk with this command: awk '!x[$0]++' is it any good compared to uniq ?

Comment: If the file is already sorted, you won't be able to beat `uniq`. That awk command will end up storing all unique lines in memory which for so big a file is probably not a good idea and has no benefit otherwise. That sed line is a convoluted (double-negation) way to write `sed '/^077/d'` though you don't need sed here as grep is more than enough. You don't need `cat` either (UUOC).

Comment: I completely agree with Stephane: just like it's hard to beat uniq in doing its specific job, grep shall be faster than sed in just filtering out the '^077'-s.

Comment: Thats great, i will run this script and see how it performs. Thank you Stephane and Leonid for your time and information :)

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '!a[$0]++' "filename" > /tmp/dup
mv -f /tmp/dup "filename"
```

Comment: please include a short description of what your commands do. It looks like you do not take the requirement '077' into account. Why is `filename` quoted?